# Как ускорить работу программы?

Tags: python

Как ускорить время обработки программы. Нужно ускорение примерно в 8 раз.

```
import random
def solution(A):
    P=len(A)-1
    Aresult=[]
    for i in range (1,P+1):
        Aresult.append(abs(sum ( A[0:(i)]) - sum (A[i:])))
        if Aresult==0:
            return Aresult
    return min(Aresult)
N=random.randint(2,100000)
A=[random.randint(-1000,1000) for i in range(N) ]
print(solution (A))
```

Условия такие:
Дается непустой массив A, состоящий из N целых чисел. Array A представляет числа на ленте.

Любое целое число P, такое, что `0 < P < N`, разбивает эту ленту на две непустые части: A [0], A [1], ..., A [P - 1] и A [P], A [ P + 1], ..., A [N - 1].

Разница между двумя частями является значение: | (A [0] + А [1] + ... + А [Р - 1]) - (А [Р] + А [Р + 1] + .. . + A [N - 1]) |

Другими словами, это абсолютная разница между суммой первой части и суммой второй части.

Напишите функцию `def (A)`, что, учитывая непустой массив A из N целых чисел, возвращает минимальную разницу, которая может быть достигнута.

Напишите эффективный алгоритм для следующих предположений:

N - целое число в диапазоне [ 2 .. 100 000 ];
каждый элемент массива A является целым числом в диапазоне [ -1,000 .. 1,000 ].

Comment: Вы бы хоть рассказали, что это вообще такое

Comment: Добавил условие задачи

Comment: Создание сечения списка - довольно дорогая операция. Частичную сумму можно накапливать, прибавляя/вычитая по одному элементу, а не пересчитывая каждый раз частичную сумму от сечения списка.

Comment: Начнём с того, что у вас в коде ошибка. Условие `if Aresult==0:` всегда будет ложным, массив никогда не бывает равен числу

Comment: Попробую вообще обойтись без этого условия. Поправил: if (abs(sum ( A[0:(i)]) - sum (A[i:])))==0:
            return 0

Comment: insolor, спасибо за подсказку. Действительно скорость возросла многократно!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так попробовал, через суммы:

```
import random
import time


class Timer:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.clock()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.clock()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start


def solution(x):
    p = len(x) - 1
    aresult = []
    for i in range(1, p + 1):
        aresult.append(abs(sum(x[0:(i)]) - sum(x[i:])))
        if aresult == 0:
            return aresult
    return min(aresult)


def solution_new(x):
    t, q, w = [], [], []
    d = len(x)
    line = range(d)
    alpha, omega = 0, 0
    for i, j in zip(line, reversed(line)):
        alpha += x[i]
        q.append(alpha)
        omega += x[j]
        w.append(omega)
    ww = list(reversed(w))
    for n in range(d-1):
        t.append(abs(q[n] - ww[n+1]))
    return min(t)

# N=random.randint(2,100000)
A = [random.randint(-1000,1000) for i in range(10000)]
with Timer() as t1:
    print(solution(A))
print('Time1: {} sec.'.format(t1.interval))

with Timer() as t2:
    print(solution_new(A))
print('Time2: {} sec.'.format(t2.interval))
#30
#Time1: 1.84718146126 sec.
#30
#Time2: 0.0129810539763 sec.
```

Comment: и чему же у нас тогда равно `reversed([1,2,3])[2]`?

Comment: Действительно. Ну ок.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, ответ уже не требуется, но это самый эффективный по времени и памяти вариант. Прирост скорости в несколько сотен раз.

```
def solution_2(A):
    f = A[0]
    t = sum(A[1:])
    mi = abs(f - t)
    for i in A[1:]:
        f = f + i
        t = t - i
        i = abs(f - t)
        if i < mi or not i:
            mi = i
            if mi == 0:
                return 0
    return min
```

Кстати, на всякий случай, arr.append(smt) медленнее, чем arr += [smt].